# How frequent are DRAM errors?

Tags: ecc, dram

How frequent are DRAM errors?  How significant a factor is heat?  Is it worth investing in ECC RAM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use ECC RAM for the next computer I build?](http://superuser.com/questions/4048/should-i-use-ecc-ram-for-the-next-computer-i-build)

Comment: @techie007: I don't see how those two are a duplicate. Advice and frequency differ...

Comment: Only if your motherboard supports it. Mostly you want this for high useage servers and the boards will be designated for it.

Comment: Yes, it is worth investing in ECC, esp for critical applications, e.g. medical, space, financial. Nowadays, even GPUs have ECC. Occurrence of soft-errors has been increasing due to several reasons, e.g. process scaling, etc. See my [survey paper](https://goo.gl/2dtMtM) for reference.  Also see this related [superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/4048/is-there-a-certain-or-measurable-advantage-to-using-ecc-ram-in-a-desktop-pc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A paper addressing this issue was published [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/sigmetrics09.pdf).

> "The goal of this paper is to answer
>   questions such as the following: How
>   common are memory errors in practice? 
>   What are their statistical properties?
>   How are they affected by external
>   factors, such as temperature and
>   utilization, and by chip-specific
>   factors, such as chip density, memory
>   technology and DIMM age?"

And this is a part from summaries:

> "This either indicates that chip size does not play a dominant role in influencing CEs or >there are other, stronger confounders in our data that we did not control for." >Similarly, "In all cases, for the same utilization levels the error rates for high versus >low temperature are very similar."

I would still recommend ECC for production systems, mind you.

Comment: Added some other points brought up by chris in my original answer and just made it all one.

Comment: You seem to have self-answered. But I don't see a frequency in your answer, are there any numbers?

Answer (score 0):

According to a study done by Google, memory errors are fairly common, affecting about 8% of DIMMS per year:

[Google study]

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/sigmetrics09.pdf

[ZDNet interpretation/summary]

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/dram-error-rates-nightmare-on-dimm-street/638